# Update Order Status using Cron Job

Tags: magento-1.8, cron, order-status, ce-1.9.0.1

I am trying to setup a Cron to automatically update order statuses that have a are in a "Processing" state in Magento.

Here is what I have so far

config.xml

```
    <orders>
        <schedule><cron_expr>0 9,11,13,15,17 * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
        <!--schedule><cron_expr>*/15 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule-->
        <run><model>orders/Status::cron</model></run>
    </orders>

</jobs>
```

And inside Status.php

```
public function updateOrderStatus($order)
{

    $order->setOrderStatus(self::STATUS_PACKING);

    $order->save();

}
```

What I would like to do is change any orders from "Processing" to "Packing" but I can't seem to find a way to do it...

If anyone knows any good resources please share.

Comment: You might need to post your whole code, as I am not 100% sure where everything is at, or if you are calling the correct functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that seem to need correcting:

- The xml is calling the wrong function

`<run><model>orders/status::cron</model></run>`

This line says to look in the `orders` module (though that it is a bit of an oversimplification) and look for a Model called `Status` and run the `cron()` function

What you probably want to do is change the line to this:

`<run><model>orders/status::updateOrderStatus</model></run>`

- The `updateOrderStatus()` function does not have access to your orders

Even though the function has a parameter called `$order` it does not act like an observer where the object is there automatically.

In other words: the order collection needs to be loaded with the following code:

`Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection');`

The collection should be narrowed to what you need (see below).

The function should end up looking like this:

```
public function updateOrderStatus()
{
    // lets get all the orders that their status is 'pending'
    $orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
         ->addFieldToFilter('status', 'pending');
     // loop through each order, set the new status and try to save, if it fails, log why (this way we'll know)
     foreach($orders as $order){
            $order->setOrderStatus(self::STATUS_PACKING);
            try{
                $order->save();
                }catch(Exception $e){
                  Mage::log('Couldn\'t save order' . $order->getId());
                  Mage::log($e->getMessage());
                 }
      }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, that really has helped me alot...

Answer (score 2):

```
<run><model>orders/status::cron</model></run>
```

1. that means magento is trying to call the cron-method in your status-model. if you have set the alias for your models correct ( in your example to "orders" ) then magento tries to find this method in /yourmodule/Model/Status.php. The function in this file should have the name "cron"
2. there will be no $order-variable to work with